# Adding fields to backend customer create section

Tags: magento, field, checkout

I would like to add three fields in customer creating section of magento backend.

- Customer Card ID
- Customer Store No
- Customer Store Name

Those fields should save into magento database then can query/show in onepage checkout ( we would like to send automatic mail of related stores customer relationship department).

Could you please help me to make such a things in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to decide if those attributes are customer attributes or customer address attributes or both together. Then add the attributes to customer and/or billing/shipping address objects (preferable with setup script) and then add the fields to all templates you might need. You also might need to extend the user data validation class.